# numerous errors handling file upload in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm using this code to process uploaded files:

```
mkdir("files/" . $id, 0700);
$path = "files/" . $id;
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        foreach($_FILES['attachments']['name'] as $f => $name)
        {
            if($_FILES['attachments']['error'][$f] == 4)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if($_FILES['attachments']['error'][$f] == 0)
            {
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachments"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                {
                    $count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`$id` is a random number taken from the database. Besides, I'm using this markup:

```
<input type="file" id="attachments" name="attachments[]" multiple="multiple" accept="*">
```

While the exact same code had worked brilliantly before, it now throws numbers of errors I can't really deduce:

> 1: mkdir(): File exists in ... on line ... (<-- now, it doesn't for granted!)
>   2: Undefined index: attachments in ... on line ... (well, it's defined also using form method post!)
>   3: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ... on line ... (which is quite clear as the above stated errors do prevent the foreach from doing its job correctly)

Yes, I made sure that I'm *actually* using `POST`. I also tried changing the file input's name from `attachments` to any other, however, scenario remains the same.

Adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` has done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1] Check for the folder rights 0777. Weather you are able to create directory or not

2] After posting form. Make sure your form has enctype = multipart/form-data tag.
In you file please check with

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
exit;
```

If you are getting any data or not? If getting data then move ahead.

Comment: "enctype = multipart/form-data tag", where to apply?

Answer (score 0):

First check if your $id really contain something, secondly your form should have attribute of `enctype = multipart/form-data` for using input type file.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Now in your case you will get the array of files you before your perform any work, see print_r of attachments:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
exit;
```